# Eclipse will not resolve dom4j library

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, dom4j

I am running Eclipse Oxygen and in a project involving Hibernate, the **dom4j** library is required. I have loaded the library in the build path and still  keep getting the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at jpa.Main.run(Main.java:38)
    at jpa.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

This is what my build path looks like:
[image: Project build path]

May I impose on your collective patience and request some help on this matter, please? I have run out of ideas on what to do here.

Much thanks

Jorge


Here's a screenshot of the Maven Dependencies
[image: Maven Dependencies]

And a copy of the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.javacodegeeks.ultimate</groupId>
  <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JPA</name>
    <properties>
        <jee.version>7.0</jee.version>
        <h2.version>1.3.176</h2.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I see you’re using Maven. Dependencies need to be added to the pom.xml directly. Did you?

Comment: I did, and that is one of the reasons I added dom4j directly to the build path. The Maven dependencies listed dom4j but it was like it wasn't there.

Comment: An image with the **Maven Dependencies** node open, and the contents of the `pom.xml` would probably help with diagnosis.